# How extract byte[] from JPG image discarding EXIF meta

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone

I need to get `byte[]` array of image data, but here is little problem. My image is a JPG file, which contains EXIF meta data, however I don't need, better I have not to take this data along with raw image bytes.

I tried to extract this by putting `Stream` (Stream contains JPG file data) to `BitmapImage` next to `WriteableBitmap` and after saving this `WriteableBitmap` to `IsolatdStorage` get `byte[]` from it. It doesn't give me good results.

Anyone of you tried this before? If so, please leave a tip.

Thanks :)

Comment: By "Array of image data", do you mean the raw RGB values? Have you looked at System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Comment: I think I don't need raw RGB because it's 3D array, I need only 1D `byte[]` array. C# for Windows Phone doesn't contain System.Drawing.Bitmap, there is only System.Windows.Media and there isn't `Bitmap`